# PHP Why I can't upload other files than images?

Tags: php

Hi all it's my first question here so let's get to the point. I am running apache server(using xampp). I wanted to make some type of files hosting. The sended file would be stored in my local folder and if i put .exe file in that folder manually it normally shows on page. But if i put it via upload.php it doesn't work(i get failed to upload).Im only able to send images through upload.php What can i do to be able to send exe files and simmilar through upload.php. My upload.php file:

```
<?php
$max_size = 5000000;
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > $max_size) {
        echo 'File is too big!';
    } 
    if($_FILES['file_upload']['type'] = 'html'){
        die('Unsupported filetype uploaded.');
    } else {
        echo 'File uploaded succesfully! ';
        echo "<strong>".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo "</strong>";
        echo '<br/>';
        if (isset($_FILES['file']['type'])) {
            echo 'Type: '.$_FILES['file']['type'].'<br/>';
        }
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Hosting/Files/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
        echo 'Direct download link:'; 
        echo'<br/>';
        echo "<strong>";
        echo'http://192.168.1.77/Hosting/Files/'.$_FILES['file']['name']; 
        echo "</strong>";
    }
} else {
   echo 'Failed to upload!';
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="container"><h2> all uploaded files are  <a href="http://192.168.1.77/Hosting/Files/"> here </a> 
     <br/> 
    </h2>
<?php
    $files = array();
    foreach (glob("http://192.168.1.77/Hosting/Files/") as $file) {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
?>
    <form  method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h3> Upload File </h3> 
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000" !accept="*.html"/>
        <br/> 
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hoping for help

Comment: @developerwjk looks like localhost to me

Comment: if you `print_r($_FILES);` after an upload, you may see a message in there

Comment: Or better still get into the habit of checking `$_FILES['file']['error']`

Comment: the field `MAX_FILE_SIZE` should be before the `file` field and it doesn't have the `accept` attribute

Comment: @RamRaider for development yes, but for debugging you want the whole thing :-)

Comment: First try to pass your code if($_FILES['file_upload']['type'] = 'html') to if($_FILES['file_upload']['type'] == 'html')